# How can I run a bash script with sudo from another bash script

Tags: bash, sudo

I am trying to run script `a` from script `b`, I didn't create script `a` and I am not sure if i want to add script `a`s location to `PATH`.

Making things even more hard to do is the fact I want to run script `a` with sudo, but not script `b` so I have `whiptail` in script `b` to ask for password and pass along with `echo $pass | sudo -S`.

my current code:

```
#!/bin/bash
input=$(whiptail --passwordbox "Enter password" 10 50 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 )
echo $input | sudo -S bash /home/<username>/multibootusb/makeUSB.sh -e -b "$1" "$2"
```

Comment: Everything looks good, what's wrong?)

Comment: See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable/27701642) (Hint: This is one of those situations.)

Comment: And you can use `read` instead of `whiptail` like so `read -s -p 'Enter password ' input`

Comment: Why prompt for the password yourself? `sudo` will prompt for a password if one is required.

Comment: @Ivan. It doesn't work. sudo says it can't find it

Comment: @tripleee Seems to be so. I'm a bit new to bash, where would I put it?

Comment: Read the page I linked, In brief, quote everything unless you specifically want the shell to perform whitespace tokenization and wildcard expansion on a value. (Hint: The password could very well contain shell metacharacters.)